# use spark to copy data across hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, distcp, bigdata

I have a situation where I have to copy data/files from PROD to UAT (hadoop clusters). For that I am using `'distcp'` now. but it is taking forever. As distcp uses map-reduce under the hood, is there any way to use spark to make the process any faster? Like we can set hive execution engine to `'TEZ'` (to replace `map-reduce`), can we set execution engine to spark for `distcp`? Or is there any other `'spark'` way to copy data across clusters which may not even bother about distcp?

And here comes my second question (assuming we can set `distcp` execution engine to spark instead of map-reduce, please don't bother to answer this one otherwise):-
As per my knowledge Spark is faster than map-reduce mainly because it stores data in the memory which it might need to process in several occasions so that it does not have to load the data all the way from disk. Here we are copying data across clusters, so there is no need to process  one file (or block or split) more than once as each file will go up into the memory then will be sent over the network, gets copied to the destination cluster disk, end of the story for that file. Then how come Spark makes the process faster if the main feature is not used?

Comment: didn't try this but maybe you could actually use Hive to read and write (create table as select) the data and run Hive over Tez or Spark. about the second part Spark's advantage is not only using memory but also better scheduling of execution stages so it is less sequential than MR

Answer (score 2):

Your bottlenecks on bulk cross-cluster IO are usually

1. bandwidth between clusters
2. read bandwidth off the source cluster
3. write bandwidth to the destination cluster (and with 3x replication, writes do take up disk and switch bandwidth)
4. allocated space for work (i.e. number of executors, tasks)

Generally on long-distance uploads its your long-haul network that is the bottleneck: you don't need that many workers to flood the network.

There's a famous tale of a distcp operation between two Yahoo! clusters which did manage to do exactly that to part of the backbone: the Hadoop ops team happy that the distcp was going so fast, while the networks ops team are panicing that their core services were somehow suffering due to the traffic between two sites. I believe this incident is the reason that distcp now has a `-bandwidth` option :)

Where there may be limitations in distcp, it's probably in task setup and execution: the decision of which files to copy is made in advance and there's not much (any?) intelligence in rescheduling work if some files copy fast but others are outstanding.

Distcp just builds up the list in advance and hands it off to the special distcp mappers, each of which reads its list of files and copies it over.

Someone could try doing a spark version of distcp; it could be an interesting project if someone wanted to work on better scheduling, relying on the fact that spark is very efficient at pushing out new work to existing executors: a spark version could push out work dynamically, rather than listing everything in advance. Indeed, it could still start the copy operation while enumerating the files to copy, for a faster startup time. Even so: cross-cluster bandwidth will usually be the choke point.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is not really intended for data movement between Hadoop clusters. You may want to look into additional mappers for your `distcp` job using the `"-m"` option.

Comment: From: 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html

I understood that it specifies maximum no of map tasks can be executed simultaneously. So is there any way to know maximum how many of them are being executed simultaneously by my cluster (suppose there are 25 splits for a job)? To what extent I can increase this number without hampering other processes?

I have 12 node PROD and 6 node UAT all with around 250 GB of physical memory and around 45 TB of disk space.

Comment: It may take some testing to determine the optimal settings.